# what is Error Messege for integer start with 1 to int.maxValue in console app in c#

Tags: c#

I want to show error message for user integer start with 1 please suggest me to show proper message.

for ex : please enter value greater then 1 
but I want alternate message.

Comment: dude, please you must even try

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, are you asking that are the commands to show text in Console? If that is the case, a quick search should have given you tons of examples, the classic "hello world" program in almost all the books/tutorials does that.

Comment: Hi, I suggest you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help page, especially the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57034609/edit) your question to add an [mcve] that helps us reproduce your problem

Comment: "I want to show error message for user integer start with 1 " how about => "Input is not allowed to start with 1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want print something on your console you should use `Console.WriteLine()`

You can do string concatenation:

`Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 1 and " + Int32.MaxValue.ToString());`

or you can use string interpolation

`Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a value greater between 1 and {Int32.MaxValue}");`

Comment: The string interpolation in your code does make no sense because it does not interpolate anything

Comment: Yes, I know but who knows myb he wants to print something else in addition. His question isn't that good so that's why, and I think he should learn about string interpolation it's a good one.

Comment: His question could be "How do I keep asking until they get the right data?" or "How do I do a Console.WriteLine?". If it is the former, you answer does not adress it. If it is the later, it does. That is the reason why I personally did not answer, because it is hard to know what his/her problem is.

Comment: Yes,That's we want

Comment: @saranglad You mean my answer above or ?

Comment: This One >> Please enter a value between 1 and " + Int32.MaxValue.ToString();

Comment: @saranglad If my answer did help you, could you tick it ? Thanks

Comment: yes.but how to do that,I'm new user of stackoverflow

Comment: @saranglad Could you join to the chat, here is the link so we don't spam the comments. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196474/sandar